# Apache 2.4 "The Request Operation Has Failed"

Tags: php, apache

Whenever I double click on ApacheMonitor.exe  and click on Start, I get this error : The Request Operation Has Failed. I've watched a youtube tutorial and I've added a couple things in httpd.conf such as:

LoadModule php7_module "c:/php/php7apache2_4.dll"

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php

## configure the path to php.ini

PHPIniDir "C:/php"

I do have PHP 7.1.5 installed, that's why I typed php7_module and not php5_module.
Any tips?